# A certain paper book sells for $25. The author receives a royalty of 12% on the first 5000 copies sold

Tags: calculus, percentages, word-problem

A certain paper book sells for $25. The author receives a
royalty of 12% on the first 5000 copies sold, 15% on the next
10000 copies sold, and 20% for any additional copies sold. Write
R, the amount of royalties in dollars as a function of x, the
number of copies sold.

This is what I have so far.

$$R(x) = \begin{cases}25*(0.12)(x)& 0 \le x \le 5000\\
 25*(0.12)(5000) + 25*(0.15)(x-5000) &  5000 < x \le 15000
\\
 25*(0.12)(5000) + 25*(0.15)(15000) + 25*(0.2)(x-15000)&  x > 15000
\end{cases}
$$

I'm not sure if they want it all in one function or if that is even possible, anyways any help would be appreciated.

Comment: That looks fine to me.

Comment: I've also edited your "LaTeX" so that it's formatted more prettily; you can look back at the question with the "edit" button to see how I did it, so that you can do it in the future as well.

Comment: ok thanks for the edit

Answer (score 0):

This is a fine function.  It gives a single output for every input.  The $15000$ in the last line should be $10000$ because that is the number of copies the $15\%$ royalty applies to.  They may want you to do the arithmetic and make the last line look like $5x-k$ for some $k$ but your version makes it clear where the terms come from.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your answer is fine. Two notes:

$1)$ The function is called a piece-wise function.

$2)$ Since Revenue = Price x Quantity and/or Royalty = Price x Quantity, it would be better to express:

$$R(x) = \begin{cases} (25\cdot0.12)(x), & 0 \le x \le 5000\\
 (25\cdot0.12)(5000) + (25\cdot0.15)(x-5000),  &  5000 < x \le 15000
\\
 (25\cdot0.12)(5000) + (25\cdot0.15)(15000) + (25\cdot0.2)(x-15000), & x > 15000
\end{cases}$$